# Find value and column header

Tags: indexing, find, powerquery, lookup

I have an issue that is going me crazy about power query excel.
I have a table with several columns and I want to find the, e.g., the first non-null value for each row. It is OK, I can do that with the usual way:
Table.AddColumn(#"Previous", "NotNull" each List.First(List.RemoveNulls({ColA,ColB,ColC})))
but I am struggling trying to find in which column appears.

I tried combinations of Table.ColumnNames and similar with no result. The raw solution with nested if's checking column by column doesn't please me.

I can do that with no effort in R/Python but I'd like to that in PQ excel.

Can anyone give me a clue? Is there any function that I'm missing?

Comment: Choose which answer worked for you then toggle the checkmark to accept the answer thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Table.ColumnNames function to get a list of the column names in your table.

Then use the List.PositionOf function to find the index of the first non-null value in each row.

Sources: [Table.ColumnName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-columnnames) and [List.PositionOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-positionof)

Answer (score 0):

Add column, custom column, named **Contents** with formula

```
= List.RemoveNulls(Record.ToList(_)){0}
```

or

```
= List.First(List.RemoveNulls(Record.ToList(_)))
```

to pick up first item on each row

Add column, custom column, with formula

```
= Table.ColumnNames(#"PriorStepNameHere){List.PositionOf(Record.ToList(_),[Contents])}
```

to find the column name containing that content (first)

[image]

full code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Contents", each List.First(List.RemoveNulls(Record.ToList(_)))),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "ColumnName", each Table.ColumnNames(Source){List.PositionOf(Record.ToList(_),[Contents])})
in  #"Added Custom1"
```